# How count the occurances inside an php array

Tags: php, associative-array

I get a this kind of a `var_dump`when put a array inside to it

```
array(3) 
[0]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#196 (5)             
{["bookID":protected]=> int(1) 
["quantity":protected]=> string(2) "10" 
["name":protected]=> string(12) "Harry Potter" 
["price":protected]=> int(700) 
["category":protected]=> string(8) "Children" } 

[1]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#184 (5) 
{["bookID":protected]=> int(3) 
["quantity":protected]=> string(1) "6" 
["name":protected]=> string(14) "Harry Potter 2" 
["price":protected]=> int(700) 
["category":protected]=> string(8) "Children" } 

[2]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#195 (5) 
{ ["bookID":protected]=> int(2) 
["quantity":protected]=> string(1) "1" 
["name":protected]=> string(9) "the Beast" 
["price":protected]=> int(544) 
["category":protected]=> string(8) "Fiction" } }

[3]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#195 (5) 
{ ["bookID":protected]=> int(2) 
["quantity":protected]=> string(1) "7" 
["name":protected]=> string(9) "the Beast 2" 
["price":protected]=> int(544) 
["category":protected]=> string(8) "Fiction" } }
```

So inside this array what Im trying to do is, to seperately get the `quantity` of each `category`. according to this example

```
Fiction quantity = 7
children quantity = 16
```

I tried to approach this way but it dint work out

```
foreach ($bookItems as $key => $bookItem) {
   $q_counts = array_count_values(
      array_column($bookItem, 'category')
   );
}
```

Can somebody help me how to get the quantity counts separately?

**Update**
getters from cartbookitem

```
public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }
```

Comment: What output does your own function give? I'd be kind of amazed if you could loop through protected properties just like that ;-)

Comment: no this is inside a symfony project. more code lines are there

Comment: OP can you post the getters from CartBookItem. I suspect you have getQuantity() and getCategory() but need confirmation.

Comment: ^ This what I was alluding to: https://3v4l.org/QGBgI

Comment: Neil Masters.. updated my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a loop like this. untested code but hopefully it will work.

```
$data=array();
foreach($bookItems as $key => $bookItem){
    if(isset($data[$bookItem->category]) && !empty($data[$bookItem->category])){
        $data[$bookItem->category]=$data[$bookItem->category]+$bookItem->quantity;
    }else{
        $data[$bookItem->category]=$bookItem->quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. category and quantity are protected class variables. Without using reflection they are not accessible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over your results and use getCategory() and getQuantity() to produce an array of categories that count up the quantities.

```
$quantities = [];

foreach ($books as $book) {
    // We need to do an isset check because += on an undefined element
    // will throw an exception.
    //
    // You can remove this with an inventive ?? ternary see
    // https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary for example uses.
    if (!isset($quantities[$book->getCategory()])) {
        $quantities[$book->getCategory()] = $book->getQuantity();   
        continue;
    }

    $quantities[$book->getCategory()] += $book->getQuantity();
}
```

If this code works you should end up with an array similar to:

```
['Children' => 16, 'Fiction' => 8]
```

[3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/pKC48)

Comment: Please try running this code somewhere before you post it, the last line already has two breaking errors in it. We're here to help people, not to provide them with code that doesn't compile. Idea of the solution is nice however!

Comment: Fixed and provided example 3v4l link of working example using OPs example.

Comment: @Loek and yet OPs will 99% of the time accept the first answer that provides no elegant solution, up to date syntax nor any explanation. The joys of SO.

Comment: The only thing we can do is post better quality answers and hope that some day, in the not too distant future, every programmer will be disciplined enough to write good software. Oh well.